# Find a value anywhere in a sheet and return the cell directly below it

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

So I have a [workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DCBGhwm8_3NMqSaV9cwLmCMo9X17rSMbFIbpoqKpBjk/edit?usp=sharing) in Google Sheets where each tab is a building (left two for simplicity). The main tab (Contact Sheet) I would like to have populate with whoever is on shift for the day; date is tracked in Contact Sheet!J2.

In Contact Sheet!B3:B10, I would like it to go to the appropriate Building Sheet and return who is working. This can be found by going to the row with the date and going one below. The same thing needs to be done for Contact Sheet!D3:D10, but here's its going two below.

I think this can be done by a combination of vlookup (hlookup?) and index/match; basically can we go into a specified sheet, find this date (it only appears once) and return the cell directly below it?

The correct version for today (2/24/2020) is in the sheet "Contact Sheet!B3:B10"

The Building sheets are linked via IMPORTRANGE() however each row format remains the same. No need to worry about the cell phone NA's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete range **B3:E**

paste this in **B3** and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDIRECT($A3&"!"&ADDRESS(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!B:B"), 0),  MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!C:C"), 0)), 
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!D:D"), 0)), MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!E:E"), 0)), 
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!F:F"), 0)), MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!G:G"), 0)),
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!H:H"), 0))+1, WEEKDAY($J$1, 11)+1))))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste this in **C3**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:B, 'TEST ROSTER'!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

paste this in **D3** and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDIRECT($A3&"!"&ADDRESS(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!B:B"), 0),  MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!C:C"), 0)), 
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!D:D"), 0)), MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!E:E"), 0)), 
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!F:F"), 0)), MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!G:G"), 0)),
 MATCH($J$1, INDIRECT($A3&"!H:H"), 0))+2, WEEKDAY($J$1, 11)+1))))
```

paste this in **E3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D3:D, 'TEST ROSTER'!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: this is solid; one of the buildings has a schedule where they begin the week with Sunday; I have added a new sheet for that case, how would I adjust the code for this in Building C?